# Configuring custom Realms for Tomcat 8.5, setting a custom mbean-descriptor

Tags: java, tomcat, mbeans, tomcat8.5

I have been tasked with Migrating our Tomcat Servers from 6.0 to 8.5.  As you can imagine, there are going to be many inconsistencies with setting up the configuration and I have very limited knowledge of setting up a web server.    What I need to do, to have our custom applications run on the new Tomcat Server, is to create a custom Realm so that our applications can validate users through their Identification cards in Active Directory.  The custom realm was configured in the conf/server.xml file.

```
<Realm className="JEDRealm"
           connectionName="CN=webapps,OU=Admin,OU=[OU],dc=[DC],DC=ds,DC=[DC],DC=[DC],DC=[DC]"
           connectionPassword="[PASSWORD]" 
           connectionURL="[SERVER URL]" 
           alternateURL="[SERVER URL]" 
           referrals="follow"
           roleBase="DC=pod,dc=ds,DC=[DC],DC=[DC],DC=[DC]"
           roleName="cn"
           roleSearch="(&amp;(member={0})(objectclass=group))"
           roleSubtree="true"
           userBase="DC=pod,DC=ds,dc=[DC],DC=[DC],DC=[DC]"
           userSearch="sAMAccountName={0}" 
           userSubtree="true" />
```

I then created a custom mbeans-descriptor file, placed it in the same directory as the JEDRealm.class file (which is a modified version of the JNDIRealm.java, then compiled as JEDRealm.class).

So after creating the JED_mbeans-descriptor, I had to set a listener for it. In Tomcat 6.0, there was:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" 
  descriptors="JED_mbeans-descriptors.xml"/>
```

However, in Tomcat_8.5, the ServerLifecycleListener has since been discontinued and I'm not sure where else to set the:

```
descriptors="JED_mbeans-descriptors.xml"
```

Here is the copy of the log file when I try to start Tomcat.

```
 03-Oct-2017 17:33:41.907 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin 
[SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Listener} Setting property 'descriptors' to 'JED_mbeans-descriptors.xml' 
did not find a matching property.
 03-Oct-2017 17:33:42.079 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement 
Begin event threw error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JEDRealm (wrong name: org/apache/catalina/realm/JEDRealm)
```

Forgive me, if I posted too much information.  I've never had to setup/configure a web server before, so my knowledge is limited.  All I had to go off of was configuration documentation of Tomcat 6.0, installed on a Windows 2008 server, running Java 7.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!